# Parse Excel Formulae

Tags: python, r, excel

Apologies in advance if this is long winded.
I need to mimic the functionality of a particular set of excel spreadsheets. This needs to be done in R. 
Getting the data etc is relatively straightforward. I need to now implement the formulae in a given worksheet.
Packages like `XLConnect` enable the extraction of the formulae in string format. For a particular worksheet the data is as follows:

```
exForm <- structure(list(r = c("A2", "B2", "A3", "B3", "A4", "B4", "A5", 
"B5", "A6", "B6", "A7", "B7"), formulae2 = c("1", "A2", "A2+1", 
"SUM(A$2:A3)", "A3+1", "SUM(A$2:A4)", "A4+1", "SUM(A$2:A5)", 
"A5+1", "SUM(A$2:A6)", "A6+1", "SUM(A$2:A7)"), x = c("2", "2", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7"), y = c("1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2")), .Names = c("r", 
"formulae2", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

#> exForm
#    r   formulae2 x y
#1  A2           1 2 1
#2  B2          A2 2 2
#3  A3        A2+1 3 1
#4  B3 SUM(A$2:A3) 3 2
#5  A4        A3+1 4 1
#6  B4 SUM(A$2:A4) 4 2
#7  A5        A4+1 5 1
#8  B5 SUM(A$2:A5) 5 2
#9  A6        A5+1 6 1
#10 B6 SUM(A$2:A6) 6 2
#11 A7        A6+1 7 1
#12 B7 SUM(A$2:A7) 7 2
```

There is a neat bit of python code that implements an original [javascript](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2004/12/excel_formula_p.html) piece of code [here](http://www.ewbi.com/ewbi.develop/samples/jsport_nonEAT.html).
I have passed my data to this set of functions using `rPython`.

```
library(rPython)
excelURL <- "http://www.ewbi.com/ewbi.develop/samples/jsport_nonEAT.py"
download.file(excelURL, "excel.py")
python.exec("execfile('excel.py')")
python.assign("test", exForm$formulae2)
python.exec('t=[]
for i in range(len(test)):
\t p.parse(test[i])
\t t.append(p.prettyprint())
')
parseForm <- python.get('t')
```

If people dont have `rPython` to hand the output of `parseForm` is

```
c("1 <operand> <number>\n", "A2 <operand> <range>\n", "A2 <operand> <range>\n+ <operator-infix> <math>\n1 <operand> <number>\n", 
"SUM <function> <start>\n    A$2:A3 <operand> <range>\n <function> <stop>\n", 
"A3 <operand> <range>\n+ <operator-infix> <math>\n1 <operand> <number>\n", 
"SUM <function> <start>\n    A$2:A4 <operand> <range>\n <function> <stop>\n", 
"A4 <operand> <range>\n+ <operator-infix> <math>\n1 <operand> <number>\n", 
"SUM <function> <start>\n    A$2:A5 <operand> <range>\n <function> <stop>\n", 
"A5 <operand> <range>\n+ <operator-infix> <math>\n1 <operand> <number>\n", 
"SUM <function> <start>\n    A$2:A6 <operand> <range>\n <function> <stop>\n", 
"A6 <operand> <range>\n+ <operator-infix> <math>\n1 <operand> <number>\n", 
"SUM <function> <start>\n    A$2:A7 <operand> <range>\n <function> <stop>\n"
)
```

So I gather now `parseForm` contains a tokenised version of the original formulae. To utilise in R would I
render the forms in `parseForm` as R expressions?

```
> ex1 <- expression(1 + A1)
> A1 <- 10
> eval(ex1)
[1] 11
```

Has anyone experience with something similar or can someone point me in the right direction. For additional information I have the data in the worksheets represented as a dataframe so for example `sheet1` here which the above are referring to is:

```
wData <- structure(c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NA, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21), .Dim = c(7L, 
                                                                              2L))
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. If you use `XLConnect`, why don't you extract the values after evaluation of formulas by Excel?

Comment: I am trying to implement the formulae in R. Its frustrating I know the motivation is similar to this blog post http://dirkgorissen.com/2011/10/19/pycel-compiling-excel-spreadsheets-to-python-and-making-pretty-pictures/

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to "mimic the functionality of a particular set of excel spreadsheets" by implementing Excel functions in R? Why you can't use R functions to mimic the functionality?

Comment: @TomasGreif I dont know what the formulae that a given sheet contains are in advance. I need to parse the sheets of the formulae they contain and implement those formulae in R.

Comment: Any excel file IN, R code out? Even if I consider simple spreadsheets (e.g. no UDFs, no recursive calculation, no add-ons), this would result in extremely inefficient R-code if you do 1:1 translation (excel formula in cell = R expression assigned to variable).

Comment: @TomasGreif yes its not pleasant the excel sheet and data are an aside to be honest we are more interested in recreating the charts interactively. The excel is background. The issue is converting tokenised strings into R formulae I am wondering if there have been similar problems before I have to start mapping tokens to R objects.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that the idea is that the input is `exForm` and the output should be `wData`.

The following can be generalized further but its sufficient for the example in the question.  Note that it assumes that any cell in `exForm` only refers to cells above it (which is the case here and would likely be the case in most situations) so that we can proceed down the rows of `exForm` linearly.

`ss` removes dollar signs giving `x1`, then transforms strings such as `A2:A4` to `wData[2:4, "A"]` giving `x2` and then converts strings with embedded `A2` and the like to strings with embedded `wData[2, "A"]` and the like.  What is left can be parsed as R and we do so.  The for loop traverses `exForm` linearly from the top applying `ss` to each cell defined in `exForm`.   No addon packages are needed.

```
SUM <- sum

ss <- function(x) {
       x1 <- gsub("$", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
       x2 <- gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+):\\1([[:digit:]]+)",
        "wData[\\2:\\3, '\\1']", x1, perl = TRUE)
       x3 <- gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)", "wData[\\2, '\\1']", x2)
       eval.parent(parse(text = x3))
    }

wData <- matrix(NA, nr = max(as.numeric(exForm$x)), nc = max(as.numeric(exForm$y)))
colnames(wData) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(wData)]

for(i in 1:nrow(exForm)) {
    x <- as.numeric(exForm$x[i])
    y <- as.numeric(exForm$y[i])
    wData[x, y] <- ss(exForm$formulae2[i])
}
```

giving:

```
> wData
      A  B
[1,] NA NA
[2,]  1  1
[3,]  2  3
[4,]  3  6
[5,]  4 10
[6,]  5 15
[7,]  6 21
```

*REVISED* A number of corrections and simplifications were made.